# Homebrew's Git 1.8.3.2 causes an 'unlink loop'

Tags: git, homebrew

I ran `brew update` and it says that 1.8.3.2 is available, so I installed it and ran `brew cleanup` to clear out the old formula. However now when I run `brew doctor` it reports the following error:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

curl
gettext
readline
```

When I `brew link` as suggested, I get this error:

```
Warning: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar.
Linking a keg-only formula, such as gettext, into the cellar with
`brew link <formula>` will cause other formulae to detect them during
the `./configure` step. This may cause problems when compiling those
other formulae.

Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.

You may wish to `brew unlink` these brews:

readline
curl
gettext
```

I've tried uninstalling Git and checking out a branch with 1.8.3.1 but the same error pops up and at this point I'm quite confused.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in the [`b1ad9b8`](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/b1ad9b861cde9e21b4dbea94816083c592f66f5d) commit to the GitHub repository. I've since learned that it is not Git specific, so keep this in mind if you are working with formulae that are "Keg Only".